# How to keep Ivy from quitting when I press backspace in the minibuffer?

Tags: ivy

It's pretty annoying when I hold down <kbd>Backspace</kbd> one character too long in the minibuffer, causing Ivy to quit and then accidentally deleting some characters in the main buffer I'm working in.


How do I change this behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ivy provides a user option to control this behaviour. Quoth [`(ivy) Defcustoms`](http://oremacs.com/swiper/#defcustoms) (edit mine):

```
-- User Option: ivy-on-del-error-function
    Specify what [to do] when ‘DEL’ (‘ivy-backward-delete-char’) throws.

    The default behavior is to quit the completion after ‘DEL’ – a
    handy key to invoke after mistakenly triggering a completion.
```

and <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>`ivy-on-del-error-function`<kbd>RET</kbd>:

```
ivy-on-del-error-function is a variable defined in ‘ivy.el’.
Its value is ‘minibuffer-keyboard-quit’

  This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.

Documentation:
The handler for when ‘ivy-backward-delete-char’ throws.
Usually a quick exit out of the minibuffer.
```

Granted, the documentation is a bit lacking, but, as the name suggests, this user option can be set to a function to be called when the user presses <kbd>DEL</kbd> one too many times. The simplest setting is to do nothing, i.e.:

```el
(setq ivy-on-del-error-function #'ignore)
```

You can also set this user option to `ignore` via <kbd>M-x</kbd>`customize-variable`<kbd>RET</kbd>`ivy-on-del-error-function`<kbd>RET</kbd>, if you prefer to use the [Custom interface](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Easy-Customization.html).

Comment: Ohhh ok. I forgot to put `setq` when I was trying that. Just curious, what's the difference between `#'ignore` and `'ignore`? And what file is `Specify what [to do] when ‘DEL’ (‘ivy-backward-delete-char’) throws.` in? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @JohnDeBord `'ignore` is short for `(quote ignore)` and `#'ignore` is short for `(function ignore)`. The value is the same symbol, but the latter tells the byte-compiler and readers that this symbol is intended to be used as a function. See [`(elisp) Anonymous Functions`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Anonymous-Functions.html) for more information.

Comment: @JohnDeBord I have already linked the (HTML) source of `Specify what [to do]...` in my answer - it is from the Ivy manual, whose Org source can be found here: https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/blob/master/doc/ivy.org.

Comment: @JohnDeBord The following PR which tries to clarify the relevant documentation was merged today: https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/pull/1535.